# Select and show states and respective cities from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table with two fields: City and State. I would like to build a simple list of all states and all respective cities, but until now could not. I would like something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>New York
    <ul>
    <li>Albany</li>
    <li>Buffalo</li>
    <li>New York City</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Illinois
    <ul>
    <li>Chicago</li>
    <li>Rockford</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I did the below select, but it list only the states. Can't find a way to show respective cities:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT states,cities FROM table ORDER BY states");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  // show here
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to check the query. It will show states and cities. You need to have any state_id, or something like that, to know which state is the city?

Comment: what does your table look like?

Answer (score 0):

states will probably be

```
$row['states']
```

cities

```
$row['cities']
```

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching states and cities to the array, and therefor you should try to print both of them:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['cities']."<br/>";
    echo $row['states']."<br/>";
}
```

but still this is not enough to give you the required result, because the query is not grouping the cities by state. but for the php part this is what you have to do.
if you want help with sql tell me :p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each DB record returned holds one state and one city, one approach would be

```
SELECT states,cities FROM table ORDER BY states, cities
```

I'm not sure you need DISTINCT, unless you might have duplicate records. That should give the results sorted by state and within a state, sorted by city.

You could keep track in the loop of the last state seen, and when it changes, close the last state's entry (`</ul></li>`). Be sure not to do that on the very first ($previousState == ''). Start the new state, output the first city, and keep outputting cities until the state changes again.

Comment: Yes, I have duplicated records. I will try something following this direction.